# How to override a magento 2 extension installed using composer

Tags: magento2, extensions, overrides

I have installed a magento 2 extension via composer. Using composer to install an extension places the file inside of the core vendor file.

File I want to edit:

```
vendor/extension-vendor/magento2-extention/view/frontend/templates/email/template.phtml
```

I have tried to place the above path inside of app/code wit hthe following path, but this did not seem to work.

```
app/code/extension-vendor/magento2-extension/view/frontend/templates/email/template.phtml
```

If I want to extend the extension that I just installed. How would I do this?

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Both answers are technically correct, but @PrincePatel had the answer that worked best for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to copy `template.phtml` in your custom theme at

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Vendor_Module/templates/email/template.phtml

flush cache and try..!

Comment: can you help on this question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/329086/how-to-override-phtml-add-a-static-image-to-phtml-file-from-the-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Check the layout file of original extension which will contain block name and template attached to it something like

```
<block class="Vendorname\Module\Block\Test"
            name="vendorname.test"
            template="Vendorname_Module::test.phtml"
            after="-"></block>
```

To overwrite this `test.phtml` file, in your module's layout file add this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="vendorname.test">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Mycustom_Test::overwritten.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

In your layout file reference the same block name which is used in original extension as per above example.

Add following code in your module's `etc/module.xml` file to load your layout after original layout file

```
<sequence>
        <module name="Vendorname_Module"/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have installed an extension which i have purchased + a theme also which is bought from somewhere   and now i want to override it too but the problem is i am unbale to figure out where i need to place it in app/design directory. should i place this extension directory from the vendor folder to my theme dir i.e
app/design/frontend/theme_vendor/theme/
or should i place it in
app/design/frontend/vendor_extension/extension