# How to override phtml / add a static image to .phtml file from the extension?

Tags: magento2, extensions, overrides, image, phtml

I'm try to add a banner image to the list.phtml, but it's not displaying.

This is what i did:

**step 1**: copied `/public_html/vendor/mirasvit/module-rewards/src/RewardsCustomerAccount/view/frontend/templates/account/list.phtml`

into

`/public_html/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Mirasvit_RewardsCustomerAccount/templates/account/list.phtml`

**step2:** upload the image to `/public_html/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/web/images/membership-banner.jpg`

**step 3:** modify the list.phtml as below

```
<?php
/** @var \Mirasvit\RewardsCustomerAccount\Block\Account\Listing $block */
$collection = $block->getTransactionCollection();
$earnRules = $block->getDisplayEarnRules();
$spendRules = $block->getDisplaySpendRules();
?>
<div class="block block-rewards-account-summary order-details-items">
    <div class="block-title">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('rewards.page.main.title'); ?>
        <strong><?= __('Points Summary') ?></strong>
    </div>

    <div class="block-content">
        <p><?= __('You have <b>%1</b> in your account.', $this->helper('Mirasvit\Rewards\Helper\Data')->formatPoints($block->getBalancePoints())); ?></p>
        <p><?= $block->getChildHtml('rewards.notification') ?></p>
        <p><?= __('test.'); ?> </p>
    </div>
    
    <!--adding this part trying to display the image-->
    <div class="block-content"> 
        <img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Infortis_Ultimo::images/membership-banner.jpg'); ?>' alt="membership-banner" width="1150" height="325">
    </div>


</div>
```

`step 4`: run php bin/magento s:s:d; php bin/magento c:f but nothing changes on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

As you have put your image in theme web folder `public_html/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/web/` so you have to use

`$block->getViewFileUrl('images/membership-banner.jpg')`

instead of `$this->getViewFileUrl('Infortis_Ultimo::images/membership-banner.jpg')`.

When you have use `Infortis_Ultimo::` it indicated that  folder is `public_html/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Infortis/Ultimo/web`.

Comment: i changed it to     <div class="block-content"> 
  <img src='<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/membership-banner.jpg'); ?>' alt="banner" width="1150" height="325">
    </div> but still not showing up. basically, even if i add some simple text it doesn't show up. do you have any ideas?